# There are no printable documents related to selected orders. [Magento 2.2.5]

Tags: magento2.2, order-status

I imported all orders into my Magento 2.2.5 from Magento 1.9, there are a few things that did not set properly, one is order status

All of my order status are blank.  I am looking for 1 of 2 things.

- Mass edit order status to completed, pending, cancelled, etc
- ability to "print shipping labels" so that the order automatically changes status

When I try and print any document (Invoice, Packing, Credit, Shipping, All) I get the error message **There are no printable documents related to selected orders.**

When I search this error on SO, there are 4 results, all 1.9, none seem to have this specific issue

Anyone have any idea's on how to do either of the processes I would like to do?

I am open to plugins/modules that will allow to set status, db edit that will manually set, custom php code that will do the job, anything, as long as it will let me set a large number of order status in a short period of time

Comment: you got the solution, facing same issue

Comment: Nothing effective